# Is the Word2Vec Spark implementation distributed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, word2vec, apache-spark-mllib

I'm relatively new to Spark and having some difficulty understanding Spark ML.

The problem I have is that I have 3TB of text, which I want to train a Word2Vec model on. The server I'm running on has around 1TB of ram and so I can't save the file temporarily.

The file is saved as a parquet that I import into Spark. The question I have is does the Spark ML library distribute the Word2Vec training? If so is there anything I need to worried about while processing such a large text file? If not, is there anyway to stream this data while training Word2Vec?

Comment: Presumably the training is distributed. Why would you worry about that though?

Comment: @mck I fear that if the training was not distributed then it would save the file locally instead of accessing it from the RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/1719  already in 2014 you can glean that parallel processing is possible - per partition.

> Quote:
>
> To make our implementation more scalable, we train each partition
> separately and merge the model of each partition after each iteration.
> To make the model more accurate, multiple iterations may be needed.

But you have to have partitoned data.

Comment: This is a good answer. I realized what I was doing wrong for anyone else interested. Basically if you're trying to train a word embedding on a very large corpus you want to see numPartitions in Spark to be greater than 1. As of now, I have been training on 1.

Comment: do you know how to determine the optimal number of partitions? So far I have been training on 1 partition and 1 iterator. Do you know any principles to determine the optimal number?

Comment: That's the zen question. In any event higher than 1 and need to take into account how many executors you have at a given point in time.